# using .find or .index of inside .find

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm having trouble using a `.includes` as the condition inside my `find` function.

```
var a = ["a.example", "b.example1", "c.example2"];
var b = "example1";
a[1].includes(b)
>> true
a[1].indexOf(b)>-1
>>true
a.find( c => { c.includes(b) });
>>undefined
a.find( c => { c.indexOf(b) > -1 });
>>undefined
```

My understanding is that find returns undefined if none of the arrays elements match the condition, or returns the first one that does.  But I cannot get this condition to work.  Am I doing something wrong? I would expect find to return a truthy `"b.example1"`

Comment: Your find function has no return statement, hence the undefined behavior ... (Remove the curly braces from the arrow function)

Comment: When using `a.find` did you define `a` beforehand?

Comment: yeah `a` was defined.  I missed a line when copying I'll add it.

Answer (score 2):

Since the `.find()` callback is filled with arrow function that use curly brackets, then put `return` statement inside the callback.

```js
a.find(c => { return c.includes(b) });
a.find(c => { return c.indexOf(b) > -1 });
```

Or remove it completelly.

```js
a.find(c => c.includes(b));
a.find(c => c.indexOf(b) > -1);
```

---

For further explanation, take a look at arrow function reference at MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions